# SQLException : no such column

Tags: java, jdbc, sqlitejdbc

I'm a new member. I have been struggling with sqlitejdbc, I thought.
I made a query to sqlite database from a java program.I got above exception.
My query is

```
select * 
from (  person as p 
        inner join company as c on p.p_id=c.p_id
     ) 
     inner join contact as ct on p.p_id=ct.p_id 
 where p.p_id=?;
```

When I put the query on navicatLite editor by placing p.p_id='1' instead of p.p_id=? , I was fine. It showed me correct values.

But from my java program. I got this exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: no such column: p.p_id
        at org.sqlite.DB.throwex(DB.java:288)
        at org.sqlite.NativeDB.prepare(Native Method)
        at org.sqlite.DB.prepare(DB.java:114)
        at org.sqlite.PrepStmt.(PrepStmt.java:37)
        at org.sqlite.Conn.prepareStatement(Conn.java:231)
        at org.sqlite.Conn.prepareStatement(Conn.java:224)
        at org.sqlite.Conn.prepareStatement(Conn.java:213)
        at programTest.test.main(test.java:19)
Java Result: 1
```

I'm sure there exists the person table and p_id field. I've searched this kind of question on this site but I found the one which is related to ruby on rails, not java. I have no idea what's wrong.

My java program is

```
import java.sql.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Htet 101
 */
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        Connection conn =
                DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite://C://Users//Htet 101//Documents//addressbook.s3db");
        PreparedStatement stat = conn.prepareStatement("select * from (person as p inner join company as c on p.p_id=c.p_id) inner join contact as ct on p.p_id=ct.p_id where p.p_id=?;");
        stat.setInt(1, 1);

        ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.print("Name : " + rs.getString("p_name") + " ");
        }
        rs.close();
        conn.close();
    }
}
```

I'm developing it using NetBeans 6.9.1, SQLite 3.7.8, SQLiteJDBC v056.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not absolutely sure, but I think it should work if you remove brackets from `From` : 
 `select * from 
 person as p
  inner join company as c on p.p_id=c.p_id

inner join contact as ct on p.p_id=ct.p_id where p.p_id=?;`

Comment: Great! It's now correct. Thanks for your help. 
Well, but why can't I add the brackets?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I didn't work with sqllite, so I cannot tell you for sure. I was really surprised that it worked from some client application; in my understanding braces hide aliases within (so `p` and `c` become invisible in outer context)

Comment: @ht3t it's the normal practice around here to mark the answer that helped solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

If the exact same query goes fine with navicat, and wrong with java, it means the driver is buggy. But make sure it is exactly the same.

Also, those brackets are suspicious - get rid of them.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I removed brackets and it has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

The brackets are likely interpreted as if you are beginning what is called an inline view in Oracle - basically a dynamically created view.  So I don't think it is a bug in the driver.