# Why doesn't this query work in SQLite but works fine in MySQL and MSAccess?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have a pretty complex SQL query as shown [in this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ccd481/1/0)

```
SELECT payer_payment.payer_id, 
       Sum(payer_payment.amount)                             AS total_paid, 
       Sum(payer_payment.pays * payments_share.single_share) AS fair_share 
FROM   payers 
       INNER JOIN (payer_payment 
                   INNER JOIN (SELECT payment_id, 
                                      Sum(amount) / Sum(pays) AS single_share 
                               FROM   payer_payment 
                               GROUP  BY payment_id) AS payments_share 
                           ON payer_payment.payment_id = 
                              payments_share.payment_id) 
               ON payers.id = payer_payment.payer_id 
WHERE  payers.user_id  = 1 
GROUP  BY payer_payment.payer_id;
```

In the fiddle it runs fine on MySQL but when I run it on a SQLite database it either throws an error citing:

> (1 no such column: payer_payment.payer_id)

When the column clearly does exist.

or simply returns 0 results, depending on the SQLite implementation (WebSQL vs SQLite.js)

What is the reason for this and is it possible to make my query more database agnostic?

Comment: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112936/sqlexception-no-such-column

Comment: Hmmm, I removed the superfluous brackets but it doesn't seem to help

Comment: in fact it then breaks it for MySQL

Comment: Have a look at your Fiddle for SQLite (with a single line at the end): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/ccd48/7. Have a look at payers->id. I think SQLFiddle for SQLite is somewat buggy and autoincrement is not working (or, which is more likely - AUTOINCREMENT is called IDENTITY in SQLite)

Comment: Have a look at this Fiddle where I have removed auto_identity: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/d9775/2 It works here

Comment: I see your fiddle works on sqlite.js, but not on websql. Additionally the query doesn't work on my local sqlite, either via laravel or phpliteadmin (which I think both utilize the PDO driver). In my laravel app the schema is already built and all the rows have functioning auto-ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQLite, you get an autoincrementing column by using [INTEGER PRIMARY KEY](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html).
(And if you rely on the actual values of `payers.id` in the query, you should give them explicitly.)

You should not try to nest joins when it is not needed:

```
SELECT payer_payment.payer_id,
       Sum(payer_payment.amount)                             AS total_paid,
       Sum(payer_payment.pays * payments_share.single_share) AS fair_share
FROM       payers
INNER JOIN payer_payment
        ON payers.id = payer_payment.payer_id
INNER JOIN (SELECT payment_id,
                   Sum(amount) / Sum(pays) AS single_share
            FROM   payer_payment
            GROUP  BY payment_id) AS payments_share
        ON payer_payment.payment_id = payments_share.payment_id
WHERE payers.user_id = 1
GROUP BY payer_payment.payer_id;
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/e514d/2)</kbd>

Comment: Many thanks, I shall try this on my local environment but the nested joins is probably the cause. Re the schema, I just made it to test the query on SQFiddle; on my Laravel app the schema is correctly built using Laravel Migrations so will have the auto-increment IDs.

Comment: It was indeed the nested joins that were the culprit, Thanks again.